# "The following classes could not be instantiated:" after using external library in eclipse ADT

Tags: android, xml-parsing, horizontalscrollview

[image]

screen shot from my app
I'm trying to build an app with sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView external library.
The app works fine in emulator but i cant see anything in xml view.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ColorPatern" >


    <it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView           
        android:id="@+id/hListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSetWallpaper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/set_wallpaper" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

What should i do to get rid of that error?

Comment: Did you import the library as a jar or as a project library?

Comment: as a project library... is there a difference?